# SQL Server, get column from a table based on the result from an subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, group-by

I have those 3 tables :

```
Table Client {
   int ClientID PK
   varchar ClientName 
}

    Table B {
       varchar Luna PK
       int NumarI PK
       int ClientID FK  <---- Foreign key from table Client 
    }

    TABLE C {
       varchar Luna FK <---- Foreign key from table b
       int NumarI FK <---- Foreign key from table b
    }
```

I have to select from table B and C after I join them some the bill that has the highest  price in every month ( the join between B and C creates a Bill table ) then I have to check wich client had that  highest bill ( the name of the client is in client table )

This query get me a table with the highest bill from every month, but I have no idea how to 
make the join with the client table so as to display what I want.

```
SELECT YEAR(d.Data) as an , MONTH(d.Data) as luna , max(suma) as suma
FROM  TabelaB d
                    join (
                             SELECT d.NumarI , d.Luna ,sum(d1.Cantitate*d1.PretVinzare)  as                                suma FROM TabelaB d left outer join TabelaC d1 on d.Luna = d1.Luna and d.NumarI = d1.NumarI

                             GROUP BY d.NumarI , d.Luna ) x on x.NumarI=d.NumarI and x.Luna = d.Luna
WHERE YEar(d.Data) >=  2012 and Year(d.Data) <= 2015
GROUP BY MONTh(d.Data ), YEAR(d.Data)
```

==========================================================================================

```
Table Client {
ClientID int PK
Name varchar
}

Table B {
       varchar Luna PK
       int NumarI PK
       int ClientID FK  <---- Foreign key from table Client
       ... other colums
}

TABLE C {
       varchar Luna FK <---- Foreign key from table b
       int NumarI FK <---- Foreign key from table b
       ... other colums
}
    Client                A left join B  
ClientID Name          Month NumarI ClientID  DATA   Price
    1     X              1    123     4              3256
    2     Y              1    435     4              3277   
    3     Z              2    145     4              8781
    4     M              7    898     3              3271
                         4    587     2              1000
                         3    541     2              3267
                         2    658     3              9980
                         2    454     1              4877


    Result 

Name    DATA            Price
 M    29-01-2013        3277
 Z    8-02-2013        9980
 Y    15-03-2013       3267
 Y   18-04-2013         1000


 And so on. 

 The idea is that I have a lots of bills in every month of the year, I have to take the highest one by month( from the join of 
 table A with table B ) and then add the specific client name that buyed that bill. How you understand.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: please give the table structure and explain the fields too....

Comment: It's not realy relevant the name of the fileds, I just need to know how can I get a specific row from a table based on a criteria from an other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some like this?

```
SELECT z.an , z.luna , z.suma , z.ClientName 
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(d.Data) as an , MONTH(d.Data) as luna , suma , c.ClientName ,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY MONTh(d.Data ), YEAR(d.Data) ORDER BY suma DESC) as [rank]
    FROM  TabelaB d
        join (
             SELECT d.NumarI , d.Luna ,sum(d1.Cantitate*d1.PretVinzare) as suma 
             FROM TabelaB d
                left outer join TabelaC d1 on d.Luna = d1.Luna and d.NumarI = d1.NumarI
             GROUP BY d.NumarI , d.Luna ) x on x.NumarI=d.NumarI and x.Luna = d.Luna
        join Client c on d.ClientID = c.ClientID
    WHERE YEar(d.Data) >=  2012 and Year(d.Data) <= 2015 ) z
WHERE z.[rank] = 1
```

If in case of multiple bills with the same price for the same day, you still want only 1 bill - you can replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()`.